# Split Data in Complex List to Single Entries Google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a complex list of public holidays that I want to be able to parse and process in Google Sheets, but right now the values are delivered to me in three columns, with multiple values in the final column, separated by commas (locations where the public holidays are observed).

I can use the "Split data to columns" option to split the values, but that doesn't solve the issue that I need one list in three columns.

**A link to the data is here:** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xvGerIveHVKqeSCczioTyDk4ksNH8TJMpaxKkXzMIUI/edit?usp=sharing

Currently when this is updated I go through a manual process to clean it up and get it in the right format, and I've tried multiple ways to try and programmatically split all the values but haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### To Three Columns

```
function toothree() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let obj = {pA:[]};
  let vo = [];
  vs.forEach(r => {
    let loc = r[2].split(',').map(e => e.trim());
    loc.forEach(l => {
      vo.push([r[0],r[1],l]);
    })
  });
  vo.unshift(['Date','Description','Location']);
  osh.clear();
  osh.getRange(1,1,vo.length,vo[0].length).setValues(vo);
}
```

Portion of Sheet1:

| Date | Description | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/3/2022 | New Years' Day (Substitute) | London |
| 1/3/2022 | New Years' Day (Substitute) | Manchester |
| 1/3/2022 | New Years' Day (Substitute) | Newcastle |
| 1/3/2022 | New Year's Day observed | Chicago |
| 1/3/2022 | New Year's Day observed | Dallas |
| 1/3/2022 | New Year's Day observed | New York |
| 1/3/2022 | New Year's Day observed | Denver |
| 1/3/2022 | New Year's Day observed | San Francisco |
| 1/3/2022 | New year's Day | Brisbane |
| 1/3/2022 | New year's Day | Melbourne |
| 1/3/2022 | New year's Day | Sydney |
| 1/6/2022 | Epiphany | Milan |

Comment: This, is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in row 1:

```
={'Current Format'!A1:C1;'Current Format'!A2:B,Index(Split('Current Format'!C2:C,","),,1)}
```

Comment: This is fantastic - except, it limits the number of resulting rows to the original array length

Comment: what's the desired length?